# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax when creating a View

Tags: mysql, sql, view

What's wrong with this code that's making it spit back an error?

My code is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_training AS 
SELECT training.train_attended, clients.client_firstname, clients.client_lastname, clients.client_swn, clients.client_id, locations.loc_id, locations.loc_title, locationsp.loc_id, locationsp.loc_title, 
FROM training 
JOIN clients ON clients.client_id = training.train_clientid
JOIN locations AS locationsp ON locations.loc_id = training.train_pickup
LEFT JOIN locations ON locations.loc_id = clients.client_winz
```

And this is the error I'm getting back:

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'FROM training JOIN clients ON clients.client_id =
> training.train_clientid JOIN' at line 3

I'm running phpMyAdmin version 3.5.2.2.

I've used this script with different values before with no issues.

Comment: You have an extra comma at the end of the select list

Comment: Why downvoted? Legitimate question. Everybody makes mistakes. Upvoted.

Comment: This question can be closed as Typo/No Repro, since typo questions aren't likely to be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra trailing comma before the `FROM` clause

```
SELECT ....,
       locationsp.loc_id, 
       locationsp.loc_title, -- <<== remove this trailing comma
FROM   training ...
```

and another error that will raise this message: `Unknown column 'locations.loc_id' in 'on clause'` is the use of `tablename` and not the alias supplied. it should be,

```
JOIN locations AS locationsp ON locationsp.loc_id = training.train_pickup
                                    ^^ should use alias here
```

Comment: `JOIN locations AS locationsp ON locations.loc_id = training.train_pickup` is an error as well

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi right. it should be `JOIN locations AS locationsp ON locationsp.loc_id = training.train_pickup`

Comment: @JW Thanks heaps! I can't believe I missed that. :)